# ISE - Command missing?

Tags: cisco-ise

We have two ISE nodes, one is Primary admin and the other is Secondary admin.

On the secondary admin node, commands in CLI such as `show application status ise` or `application` are missing.

Is this expected behavior ? Will they appear if I promote my secondary admin node to Primary ? And once promoted to primary admin, will the command be now missing on the original primary admin ?

My ISE nodes are running 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior ? Will they appear if I promote my secondary
>   admin node to Primary ? And once promoted to primary admin, will the
>   command be now missing on the original primary admin ?

Yes, this is normal behavior on Cisco ISE 2.3.

The command will be available when you promote the secondary admin node to primary and vice versa, the before primary node will no longer have the commands.